# Grails: Criteria query fail on join tables?

Tags: hibernate, grails, join, criteria

We have a problem working with Grails (2.3.7), that it's related with Criteria Queries and mappings. The problem is after defining the criteria and trying to list the results, Hibernate seems that is not adding the mapping tables to the query, and therefore, the query fails.

Right now we have 3 tables related: Users, Competitions + UserCompetition who has the relationship among the other 2 tables with a composite primary key, who has a reference to each two tables as a foreign key.

Here there are the definition of our domains:

```
class User {
(...)
static hasMany = [competitions:Competition]

static mapping = {
    table "users"
(...)
    competitions joinTable: [name: 'usersCompetitions',
        key: 'userId',
        column: 'competitionId']
}


class Competition {
(...)
static hasMany = [users:User]

static belongsTo = User

static mapping = {
    table "competitions"
    id column: 'competitionId'
    users joinTable: [name: 'usersCompetitions',
        key: 'competitionId',
        column: 'userId']
}
}


class UserCompetition implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

Competition competition
User user
boolean planning

static mapping = {
    table "usersCompetitions"
    id composite: ['user', 'competition']
    competition column: 'competitionId'
    user column: 'userId'
}


boolean equals(other) {
    if (!(other instanceof UserCompetition)) {
        return false
    }

    other.user?.id == user?.id &&
            other.competition?.id == competition?.id
}

int hashCode() {
    def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
    if (user) builder.append(user.id)
    if (competition) builder.append(competition.id)
    builder.toHashCode()
}

static UserCompetition get(long userId, long competitionId) {
    UserCompetition.where {
        user == User.load(userId) &&
                competition == Competition.load(competitionId)
    }.get()
}
```

}

And finally, we are trying to retrieve some data from UserCompetitions using Criteria:

```
def c = UserCompetition.createCriteria()
def competitions = c.list{
        createAlias("competition", "comp")
        and{
            isNotNull("comp.startDate")
            gt("comp.startDate", now)
        }
        eq("user.id",user.id)
        ne("planning",true)
        maxResults(3)
        order("comp.startDate", "asc")
    }
```

That's what we get:

```
Message: Unknown column 'comp1_.startDate' in 'where clause'
```

And this is the query generated by Hibernate and as you can see, it didn't add the relation with the Competition table:

```
select this_.userId as userId0_0_, this_.competitionId as competit2_0_0_, this_.planning as planning0_0_ from usersCompetitions this_ where (comp1_.startDate is not null and comp1_.startDate>?) and this_.userId=? and this_.planning<>? order by comp1_.startDate asc limit ?
```

We are trying to understand whats going on, but we are not able to understand why Hibernate is not adding the mapping table to the query :-?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related about how Grails is interpreting all the mappings that uses the `joinTable`.

We have deleted all the `joinTable`s references inside `User` and `Competition` domain classes and linking them through `UserCompetition` instead of each other and the queries started to work.

```
class User {
(...)
static hasMany = [competitions:UserCompetition]

static mapping = {
    table "users"
(...)
    /* competitions joinTable: [name: 'usersCompetitions',
        key: 'userId',
        column: 'competitionId'] */
}


class Competition {
(...)
static hasMany = [users:UserCompetition]

static belongsTo = User

static mapping = {
    table "competitions"
    id column: 'competitionId'
    /* users joinTable: [name: 'usersCompetitions',
        key: 'competitionId',
        column: 'userId'] */
}
}
```